# Django - populate model with foreignkey via csv import?

Tags: django, csv

I've trying to setup a model to be populated with a csv file, and to use one of the fields as a foreignkey:

First, I tried creating a model from an existing postgresql table using inspectdb, migrating and then change the type of the field I want to relate from charfield to foreignkey, but I got errors

Then I tried creating an empty model with the inspectdb description, then importing a csv in postgresql, and finally changing the field i want to foreignkey. In the admin site I can view the imported data and the relations, but when I query the model I got another error with the foreignkey field, and it wont let me migrate (cant recognize the charfield, it asks for integer)

-the csv column I want for a foreignkey is charfield, when i create the model before importing the csv i got an error, then checking the datatype in the postgres table is says integer, can it be set to charfield??

What workflow work best for importing a csv to a model and use one of the fields as a foreignkey (charfield type)??

Thanks

This is the model to be related to :

```
class D_Roles(models.Model):
    predio = models.CharField(max_length=254)
    dest = models.CharField(max_length=254)
    dir = models.CharField(max_length=254)
    rol = models.CharField(max_length=254)
    vlr_tot = models.FloatField()
    ub_x2 = models.FloatField()
    ub_y2 = models.FloatField()
    instrum = models.CharField(max_length=254)
    codzona = models.CharField(max_length=254)
    nomzona = models.CharField(max_length=254)
    geom = models.MultiPointField(srid=32719)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.rol

    class Meta():
        verbose_name_plural = "Roles SII"
```

The models I want to populate with csv:

```
class Dom2015CertInf(models.Model):
    id = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=80)
    nombre_archivo = models.CharField(max_length=180, blank=True, null=True)
    derechos = models.CharField(max_length=120, blank=True, null=True)
    dir_calle = models.CharField(max_length=120, blank=True, null=True)
    dir_numero = models.CharField(max_length=120, blank=True, null=True)
    fecha_certificado = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    numero_certificado = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    numero_solicitud = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    #Original field from inspectdb
    #rol_sii = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    #FOREIGNKEY Changed after creating the model and importing the csv
    rol_sii = models.ForeignKey(D_Roles, db_column='rol_sii', on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=0)
    zona_prc = models.CharField(max_length=120, blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.numero_certificado)

    class Meta:
        managed = True
        verbose_name_plural = "2015 Certificados Informaciones Previas"
        ordering = ['numero_certificado']
```

Comment: Post some code to show what you're doing. If you want a foreign key, then that's not a `CharField`, that should be an `IntegerField` at the database level. It points at the ID of the related object.

Comment: Thanks, I posted the code I have, I forgot to mention that the model that I want to relate to is spatial data, a geodjango imported shp file , if that's relevant for the relation